# Import Svelte component from a path which is set in string variable

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am trying to import Svelte component from path which is set in string variable.

When I import the component using directly, it is working:

```
import("./Component.svelte").then(module => {
    Component2 = module.default;
})
.catch(error => {});
```

But, when I try to define a variable with the path of component and import it, it doesn't:

```
let filePath = "./Component.svelte"
import(filePath).then(module => {
  Component2 = module.default;
})
.catch(error => {});
```

Is there anyway that I can import component with variable source path?

Here is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/90c697630ba445cea0076f5c032ec4ca?version=3.55.1)

Comment: What build system do you intend to use or this this *only* about the REPL?

Comment: I am using Sveltekit's latest versing using Vite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Vite, you can dynamically import components, but there are some restrictions, e.g. if the component is in a subdirectory, you can import using:

```js
import(`./components/${name}.svelte`)
```

You cannot have a fully dynamic import because otherwise the build system would not know what files to include in the build (and Svelte files have to be compiled to be usable).

All dynamic import limitations are documented [here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations).

The rules are in short:

- Imports must start with `./` or `../`.
- Imports must end with a file extension
- Imports to your own directory must specify a filename pattern
- Globs only go one level deep